# Apache deflate ignores javascript

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, gzip, deflate

I have set up deflate in my htaccess. Everything works fine, **except** for some reason javascript files are being ignored. I tried every possible combination of `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE` with multiple mime-types but all without effect. Its not a caching issue, it actually let me believe it was working until I came home a double checked. Currently I am using this [tool](http://tools.pingdom.com/fpt), site is [here](http://www.triangel.sk). You can clearly see that everything is compressed except js files (missing correct Content-Encoding unlike the js from google and css files).

Here is my current htaccess file:

```
<FilesMatch "\.(tpl|ini|log)">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$">
    SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</FilesMatch>

ExpiresActive On
ExpiresDefault A0

<FilesMatch "\.(flv|ico|pdf|avi|mov|ppt|doc|mp3|wmv|wav)$">
    ExpiresDefault A3024000
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|swf)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    ExpiresDefault A3024000
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html|js|css)$">
    FileETag MTime Size
    ExpiresDefault A604800
    Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>
```

I had the DEFLATE filter out of file match as well.

Any help is appreciated, regards.

Answer (score 1):

Hi im using this for my site, im just using AddOutputFilterByType to certain mime types. This is another approach i know, but maybe usefull.

ive noticed that in youre site javascript mime type is application/x-javascript

```
<Location />
  <IfModule mod_deflate.c>

    # compress content with type html, text, xml, css and js
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/css text/xml
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript application/x-javascript

    # Netscape 4.x has some problems...
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

    # Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

    # MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
    # the above regex won't work. You can use the following
    # workaround to get the desired effect:
    BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

    # Don't compress images
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \
    \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary

    #para que mis archivos pdf no los comprima
    SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^(.*)pdf(.*)\.php$" no-gzip dont-vary

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    # properly handle requests coming from behind proxies
    Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    #Header append Vary User-Agent
    </IfModule>
  </IfModule>
</Location>
```

Comment: This doesnt work either :/ Its like something is blocking js from being gzipped...